# Is there good way to run a script only when the user install my npm package manually?(not installed by dependency)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm under developing my npm package and I want to run a specific script only when user installed my package manually like `npm install my-package --save-dev` or something npm command.

I'd not like to run the command when the package was installed via package dependency.
For example, My package is dependency of the other package `other-package`.
Even if the user installed `other-package` manually and npm should install `my-package` as dependency, I'd not like to run the script.

Is there good way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm` has a set of [scripts that will automatically run](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) when `npm` is launched a particular way. The scripts you might be interested in are:

> - `prepublish`: Run BEFORE the package is published. (Also run on local `npm install` without any arguments.)
> - `publish`, `postpublish`: Run AFTER the package is published.
> - `preinstall`: Run BEFORE the package is installed
> - `install`, `postinstall`: Run AFTER the package is installed.

There is no event that exactly matches your criteria but you could use one of the `install` events and then have an intermediate script that detects the `npm` command line options before your actual script.

Due to the (imo horrible) way `prepublish` works, a number of people have written modules to do a similar task and these could easily be adapted to your requirements.

[`iarna/inpublish`](https://github.com/iarna/in-publish) is a good example. It check's `process.env['npm_config_argv']` for the existence of `/^i(n(s(t(a(ll?)?)?)?)?)?$/`

Using the following `package.json` setup:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "my-install && install-manual-tasks || not-my-install"
}
```

If `my-install` uses `process.exit(0)` then `install-manual-tasks` will run. If you `process.exit(1)`, `not-my-install` will clean up so the `npm` task doesn't fail.

I think this setup actually has an issue. If your `install-manual-tasks` fails, the exit status is silenced and the `npm` task won't fail but it's a start at least. You could work around this by doing all your checks in the `install-manual-tasks` script, then you don't need use the shell tricks to run multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at https://superuser.com/a/105389/627275 to see how to create a shell function that acts as an alias to a command. This way, `npm install` would act as an alias to whatever you want to run in reality. It could also be an alias to `bash something.sh & npm install`.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: I'm afraid to misunderstanding what you mean. However, making alias for command in bash would not help. Because it is just run in my local. I want to publish my package in npm and act like what I say. But, your comment would help me to come up with new idea. Thank you for your help.